# Spring MVC hangs on POST request with Content-Length header but no POST body

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, tomcat8

I have a server written in Java with Spring MVC (Spring BOOT) running under Tomcat. We are noticing that some clients are sending a POST request with a content length header but no entity body. When this request comes in the request hangs for 20s and then a response (400) comes back from the server.

Attaching a profiler shows that the server thread that is hung has the following stack.

> "http-nio-31114-exec-4" #52 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fc26e6b6000 nid=0x9f03 waiting on condition [0x0000700010a1f000]
>    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
>     at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>     - parking to wait for   (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
>     at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
>     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1037)
>     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1328)
>     at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:277)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.awaitLatch(NioEndpoint.java:1106)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.awaitReadLatch(NioEndpoint.java:1108)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:184)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:235)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:216)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1233)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1182)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:713)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$300(Http11InputBuffer.java:40)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1063)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:140)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:257)
>     at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:541)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:326)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:634)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.readByte(InputBuffer.java:337)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:93)
>     at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
>     at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:139)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver$EmptyBodyCheckingHttpInputMessage.(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:319)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:192)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:157)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:130)
>     at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:124)
>     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
>     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:131)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter.doFilter(ExceptionLoggingFilter.java:48)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:61)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130)
>     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
>     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105)
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at com.fabrikam.valve.RequestTraceValve.lambda$invoke$0(RequestTraceValve.java:41)
>     at com.fabrikam.valve.RequestTraceValve$$Lambda$423/855335917.accept(Unknown Source)
>     at com.fabrikam.tomcat.request.trace.RequestTraceInitializer.invoke(RequestTraceInitializer.java:140)
>     at com.fabrikam.valve.RequestTraceValve.invoke(RequestTraceValve.java:39)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     - locked  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

The servlet looks like this:

> @CrossOrigin
>     @RequestMapping(path = "/event/{apikey}/{anonymousId}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
>     public void clickRawPost(
>             @PathVariable String apikey,
>             @PathVariable String anonymousId,
>             @RequestBody(required = false) String postContent,
>             HttpServletRequest request,
>             HttpServletResponse response)
>             throws IOException {

The repro command is as follows:

> $ time curl -s http://localhost:8080/event/test/foo  -H 'content-type:
>   application/json' -H 'content-length: 100' -X POST -v

This command times out in 20s.

I was expecting it to fail very fast, since no entity body is present in the request.

Comment: The client waits for Spring's response, and Spring waits for the client's body. The client explicitly stated that it will send 100 bytes, how do you want Spring to know it won't send them? The issue is on your client's side. Fix the client. Or force the client to disconnect without waiting for Spring's response.

Comment: Yes I know.. the problem is that I have no control over the client. Our service is public, and we are getting hammered with requests like that.

Comment: I don't think Spring can handle this by itself. Apache has a mod to handle that kind of case, maybe you can create a filter on the same principle: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html#requestreadtimeout